# DatePicker throws Uncaught TypeError of undefined in onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, material-ui

I have a DatePicker which is throwing the following error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`.

My data is being pulled from an API where some items date field is null.  Initial render of the page is fine, where the TextFields and 2 empty date pickers display, but when I input a date, the error is thrown.

When an item does have a date value, it is returned from the API like this `Aug 12 2020 12:00AM`

I want to disregard the time and append the date to the date picker when the there is a date present.  If there is no date, I want to append todays date.

The following code will display a TextField or a DatePicker based on the value of `FieldType`.

Here is my API request:

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState("");

const fetchDetails = async () => {
        setBusy(true);
        setDetails(await fetch(`/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details`).then((response) => response.json()));
        setBusy(false);
};
```

This is how I switch between TextFields, Selects and the DatePicker:

```
return (
<Box>
    {details["fields"]?.map((row, index) => {
    if (row?.FieldType === "Text" || row?.FieldType === "Decimal" || row?.FieldType === "Number") {
        return (
            <TextField
                value={row?.Value || ""}
                onChange={(e) => {       
                    setDetails((prev) => {
                        const update = [...prev.fields];
                        update[index] = {
                            ...update[index],                
                            Value: e.target.value,
                        };
                        return { ...prev, fields: update };            
                    });
                }}
            />
        );
    }
    if (row?.FieldType === "Date") {        
        return (
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DatePicker
                    label={row?.FieldName || ""}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                    value={row?.Value || ""}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setDetails((prev) => {
                            const update = [...prev.fields];
                            update[index] = {
                                ...update[index],
                                Value: e.target.value,
                            };
                            return { ...prev, fields: update };
                        });
                    }}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>
        );
    } 
    })}
</Box>
)
```

Comment: if u use material ui you can use: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/ easly than datepicker

Comment: ``@mui/x-date-pickers`` results in package errors on my ``node_modules``.  This is why I am using the old ``@mui/lab packages``, but the results are the same.  Both the mui-x and mui/lab DatePickers throw the same error.

Comment: I am using the Material UI version 4 in my project, will there be any problems if I install the version Data picker that you put in your answer? And if not, I hope you can give me the steps for installation and use

Comment: I am using ``@mui/material`` version 5.6.0, ``@mui/lab`` version 5.0.0-alpha.67 and ``@date-io/date-fns`` version 2.13.1.  When installing date-io, do it like this.  ``npm i date-fns @date-io/date-fns```.  This avoids any module errors with the date-fns packages.